# tailwind 3 not loading completely in rails + shakapacker + HAML (webpacker@v6, webpack@v5, postcss@v8)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, tailwind-css, haml, postcss

**UPDATE 2021-09-08: TL;DR.** **Tailwind was not being applied to HAML templates.**

Migrating a project to `shakapacker` which uses `webpack@v6` and `postcss` under the hood. All other front-end CSS assets are loading properly it seems, except for TailwindCSS.

To make debugging simpler, I removed all other CSS imports from the main file except for Tailwind. I also created the following test HTML page to see if Tailwind CSS styles are applied.

###### `test.html`

```
...
<div class="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg">
  <div class="px-6 py-4">
  <div class="font-bold text-xl mb-2">
    The Coldest Sunset
  </div>
  <p class="text-gray-700 text-base">
      Lorem ipsum
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

When I view this page, it looks plain, and just text – no shadows, padding, font weights, etc. applied. When I look at the generated CSS output, it seems that only Tailwind's reset styles are loaded, nothing else.

You can see the output here: http://codebin.org/view/bba03ee2.

#### UPDATE 2022-AUG-11

As suggested by the comments below, I ran `yarn run tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/packs/styles/application.scss -o ./output.css` and it produced the following error:

```
.../app/assets/packs/styles/application.scss:4:1: Unknown word
You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser
```

That error is pointing to the first commented out line: `// @tailwind "base";` which makes sense since `// double forward-slash comments` are a `SASS/SCSS` feature and not standard `CSS`.

However, I thought that including `sass` and `sass-loader` would handle this according to the `shakapacker` installation instructions.

Because of this, I explicitly specified the loaders in `webpack.config.js` (see below) and the error is still happening.

I've included all the relevant files below.

#### CONFIG FILES

###### `application.scss` (imports all the CSS assets):

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
// @tailwind "base";
// @tailwind "components";
// @tailwind "utilities";
```

Using `@import` or `@tailwind` produces the same result.

###### `application.js` (imports `application.scss`)

*I've only included the relevant lines of code.*

```js
...
import "./styles/application.scss"
...
```

###### `packages.json`

```js
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7",
    "@babel/runtime": "7",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^7.0.3-1",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^7.0.3-1",
    "@rails/ujs": "^7.0.3-1",
    "babel-loader": "8",
    "coffee-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "coffeescript": "^2.7.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "9",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jquery-ujs": "^1.2.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^7.7.2",
    "select2": "^4.1.0-rc.0",
    "shakapacker": "6.5.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "5",
    "tributejs": "^5.1.3",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "5",
    "webpack-assets-manifest": "5",
    "webpack-cli": "4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.3",
    "webpack-merge": "5"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "./node_modules/shakapacker/package/babel/preset.js"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "defaults"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "sass": "^1.54.3",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
  }
}
```

###### `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const { webpackConfig, merge } = require('shakapacker')

// See the shakacode/shakapacker README and docs directory for advice on customizing your webpackConfig.

const sassLoaderConfig = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          "style-loader",
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          "css-loader",
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};

const options = {
  resolve: {
      extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.sass', ".scss", ".css", ".module.sass", ".module.scss", ".module.css", ".png", ".svg", ".gif", ".jpeg", ".jpg"]
  }
}

module.exports = merge(webpackConfig, sassLoaderConfig, options);
```

###### `postcss.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
    require('postcss-preset-env')({
      autoprefixer: {
        flexbox: 'no-2009'
      },
      stage: 3
    })
  ]
}
```

###### `tailwind.config.js`

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './app/**/*.html',
    './app/**/*.html.slim',
    './app/**/*.html.erb',
    './app/**/*.js'    
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

###### `webpacker.yml`

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpacker-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/assets

  # You can have a subdirectory of the source_path, like 'packs' (recommended).
  # Alternatively, you can use '/' to use the whole source_path directory.
  source_entry_path: /packs

  # If nested_entries is true, then we'll pick up subdirectories within the source_entry_path.
  # You cannot set this option to true if you set source_entry_path to '/'
  nested_entries: true 

  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/webpacker
  webpack_compile_output: true
  # See https://github.com/shakacode/shakapacker#deployment
  webpacker_precompile: true

  # Location for manifest.json, defaults to {public_output_path}/manifest.json if unset
  # manifest_path: public/packs/manifest.json

  # Additional paths webpack should look up modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  additional_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Select loader to use, available options are 'babel' (default), 'swc' or 'esbuild'
  webpack_loader: 'babel'

  # Set to true to enable check for matching versions of shakapacker gem and NPM package - will raise an error if there is a mismatch or wildcard versioning is used
  ensure_consistent_versioning: false

  # Select whether the compiler will use SHA digest ('digest' option) or most most recent modified timestamp ('mtime') to determine freshness
  compiler_strategy: digest
  
  extract_css: true

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true
  compiler_strategy: mtime

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    # Hot Module Replacement updates modules while the application is running without a full reload
    hmr: false
    # If HMR is on, CSS will by inlined by delivering it as part of the script payload via style-loader. Be sure
    # that you add style-loader to your project dependencies.
    #
    # If you want to instead deliver CSS via <link> with the mini-extract-css-plugin, set inline_css to false.
    # In that case, style-loader is not needed as a dependency.
    #
    # mini-extract-css-plugin is a required dependency in both cases.
    inline_css: true
    # Defaults to the inverse of hmr. Uncomment to manually set this.
    # live_reload: true
    client:
      # Should we show a full-screen overlay in the browser when there are compiler errors or warnings?
      overlay: true
      # May also be a string
      # webSocketURL:
      #  hostname: "0.0.0.0"
      #  pathname: "/ws"
      #  port: 8080
    # Should we use gzip compression?
    compress: true
    # Note that apps that do not check the host are vulnerable to DNS rebinding attacks
    allowed_hosts: "all"
    pretty: true
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    static:
      watch:
        ignored: '**/node_modules/**'

test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, @Alex. I created a test page that uses `tailwind` styles. I added the test page HTML to the original question above. In short, only styles in the generated output are being applied. Things like shadows, padding, and font weights are not being applied.

Comment: I tried a fresh install with everything you posted, it's working, I can't even break it. maybe something in `webpacker.yml` if you can post it as well. in the meantime, try to narrow it down: rename scss to `application.css` just leave `@tailwind utilities;` (no "quotes"). then run `npx tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/packs/styles/application.css -o ./output.css`, see what that outputs. also clear any cache/packs/assets.

Comment: Thanks @Alex! I'll give that a try. I added `webpacker.yml` to the end of the original question above.

Comment: Interesting! Getting this error coming up: `You tried to parse SCSS with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-scss parser` Shouldn't the `sass` and `sass-loader` handle that?

Comment: @Alex I tried specifying the loaders explicity in `webpack.config.js` (updated above) and the error is still happening.

Comment: `tailwindcss` command only knows `css`, it's not going through webpack. remove `//` comments. i just want to make sure actual tailwind is working by itself. i tried your `webpacker.yml` config, still compiles for me. you can probably create a fresh app, it should just work, and then compare configs with your app.

Comment: Thanks @Alex. I removed al the `//` comments. There were no errors reported this time. I'll try your suggestion of creating a fresh app and compare the differences.

Comment: @Alex I created a Rails 6.1.6.1 project with Shakapacker and Tailwind and its reporting similar errors as before. It's complaining that the '@' symbol isn't recognized. I've made a repo here: https://github.com/johnnyicon/rails6-shaka-tailwind

Comment: Looking good, @Alex. I got the test project to work by adding `sass` and `postcss`. See commit here: https://github.com/johnnyicon/rails6-shaka-tailwind/commit/11596e52ba36f94ee8566e46c78dce909fce5af5 Now to see what the differences are with my real project. Onward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after all the hunting around, the culprit was in the `tailwind.config.js` file. I failed to mention that I was using `HAML` templates, and I forgot to add `*.haml` extensions to the tailwind configuration.

I'll update the original question so includes HAML as part of the problem.

The solution is below.

```js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')
module.exports = {
  content: [
    ...
    './app/views/**/*.html.haml',
    './app/views/**/*.haml',
    ...
  ],
  plugins: [
      ...
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Best I can do is to explain what I know, maybe something will nudge you in the right direction.

```bash
$ rails _6.1.6.1_ new shaka --skip-javascript
$ cd shaka

# https://github.com/shakacode/shakapacker#installation
$ bin/bundle add shakapacker 
$ bin/rails webpacker:install

# https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation
$ bin/yarn add tailwindcss
$ bin/yarn tailwindcss init

$ bin/rails g controller Home index
```

Update a few files, so we can test everything:

```c
// app/views/home/index.html.erb
<h1 class="text-red-500">Am I red?</h1>

// app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
// only need the asset pipline, for now
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "tailwind.bundle" %>

// tailwind.config.js
// update content to include views
content: [ "./app/views/**/*.html.erb" ],
// alternatively, since we need all the views anyway, just get them all, 
// it'll grab a few unneeded files, like .jbuilder, no big deal:
// content: [ "./app/views/**/*" ],

// app/javascript/styles/tailwind.css
@tailwind utilities;
```

Right now `tailwindcss` is not integrated into `shakapacker`, `webpack` or `sass`. We can run *tailwindcss* command to compile our styles and let *sprockets* serve them.

```bash
$ bin/yarn tailwindcss -i ./app/javascript/styles/tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/stylesheets/tailwind.bundle.css --watch

# start the server and open http://localhost:3000/home/index
$ bin/rails s

# you should see a red title
```

You can `@import` other files as well (internally it uses *postcss-import*):

```scss
// app/javascript/styles/tailwind.css
@import "./imported.css";
@tailwind utilities;

// app/javascript/styles/imported.css
h1 { background-color: yellow; }
```

This is what *tailwindcss* does on its own (`v3.1.8`). Other functionality is added by overriding *postcss* config.
*https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#using-post-css-as-your-preprocessor*

```js
// postcss.config.js

module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    "postcss-import": {},        // process @import
    "tailwindcss/nesting": {},   // add sass like nesting
    tailwindcss: {},             // then let tailwind do its thing
  }
}
```

```scss
// app/javascript/styles/imported.css

body {
  h1 { 
    background-color: green; 
  }
}
```

Override *postcss* config with `--postcss` flag:

```bash
$ bin/yarn tailwindcss --postcss postcss.config.js -i ./app/javascript/styles/tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/stylesheets/tailwind.bundle.css --watch
```

BTW, this is how *cssbundling-rails* does it. If you need to import your css through *webpack*, a few things need to be changed.

```js
// app/javascript/application.js
import "./styles/tailwind.css"
```

If you try to run `bin/webpack-dev-server` you get:

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/styles/tailwind.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
```

*Webpack* doesn't know how to deal with css. Add css loader:

```
$ bin/yarn add css-loader mini-css-extract-plugin
```

Add stylesheet pack to layout:

```rb
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

# don't need this 
# stylesheet_link_tag "application", "tailwind.bundle", media: "all"

<%= javascript_pack_tag "application" %>
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag "application" %>
```

Start `bin/webpack-dev-server` and you should get the same result red/green title. If you look at the generated css file:

```css
/*!****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************!*\
  !*** css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].use[2]!./app/javascript/styles/tailwind.css ***!
  \****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************/
body h1 { background-color: green; }
.inline { display: inline; }
.text-red-500 { --tw-text-opacity: 1; color: rgb(239 68 68 / var(--tw-text-opacity)); }


/*# sourceMappingURL=application.css.map*/
```

The comment at the top shows that *tailwind.css* was processed by `postcss-loader` and then by `css-loader`.
*https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders#configuration*

We know our *postcss* config was working, it has *tailwindcss* hooked up, *tailwindcss/nesting* and *postcss-import*. So you get the same result.

If you have to use *sass*, just slap it on top and everything should still work. First, rename every `css` to `scss`. You should get an error from *webpack*, because it doesn't know how to deal with `scss`. So we need sass loader:

```bash
$ bin/yarn add sass-loader sass
```

Sass does *@import* and nesting, so these are not needed anymore:

```
"postcss-import": {},
"tailwindcss/nesting": {},
```

After *sass* is done, the only thing left to do is to process `@tailwind`, `@layer`, `@apply` and other *tailwind* directives.

```js
// postcss.config.js

module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
  }
}
```

That is everything I know. Also, I haven't touched any *webpack* configs at all, *shakapacker* does a lot of it [automatically](https://github.com/shakacode/shakapacker/tree/master/package/rules). I've tried using `assets/packs` directory, same result. Watch the order of the imports:

*https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#build-time-imports*

I'm not sure who does the importing in this stack, it should be *sass*. Although, *css-loader* also knows how to *@import*. And if you leave *postcss-import* it also knows how to *@import*. I bet every one of them does it differently.

Things that I've skipped: `autoprefixer`, `style-loader`, `css-minimizer-webpack-plugin`.

Comment: Alex, thank you so much for your help on this! I figured out the reason this was happening, and it's really silly. I'll post the solution. I'd love to give you the checkmark for all your help, but that wouldn't be helpful for those looking for a solution. Hope you understand!